# How to get the directory of the current DLL

Tags: c++, go

I will build c-shared in golang `-o config.dll`.

Let's say the directory is `c:\test\config.dll`

In mail.dll, I'm going to open a configuration file.
This file is in the directory of config.dll.
`c:\test\config.json`

I'm calling it in c++ `c:\test\c++.dll`.

In c++ I use

```
{ // NB: XP+ solution!
    HMODULE hModule = NULL;
    GetModuleHandleEx(
        GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS,
        (LPCTSTR)GetCurrentModule,
        &hModule);

    return hModule;
}
WCHAR path3[MAX_PATH + 1] = { 0 };
        HMODULE hm = GetCurrentModule();
        ::GetModuleFileName(hm, path3, MAX_PATH);
        PathRemoveFileSpec(path3);
// path3 c:\test\c++.dll
```

What is the equivalent of this in Go?

I try to use

```
os.Getwd()
runtime.Caller(1)
os.Args[0]
os.Executable()
```

I want to get directory `c:\test\`

Answer (score 0):

You can use cgo to call the same function in whatever library it exists.